# Why and where does my PHP code suddenly get cached?

Tags: php, symfony, firefox, caching

Since about a week I've got a very strange caching problem. I did not make any changes I know of which could possibly lead to this problem.

It happens using:

1. PHP 8.1.9
2. Apache 2.4.48 or the built-in symfony web server
3. PHPStorm or notepad++
4. symfony or just plain PHP
5. Firefox or Edge

My output gets cached somehow. I can completely destroy the PHP code or rename/delete files -> still displayed correctly. Some time later it finally refreshes and displays the errors. The errors themselves don't get cached. Fixing them immediately returns the script to the expected behaviour. I've already disabled caching inside Firefox (in the settings and setting *disk.cache.enabled* to *false*), but it happens with Edge, too.

The only common thing my experiments share is the PHP version/installation, it *probably* does not have to do anything with Apache, symfony or the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide example of these errors?

Comment: These are only the errors I get when I leave e. g. a <?php ecasdads%"§$; ?> inside a file. It still gets displayed correctly for some time as if nothing changed inside the file, then a few minutes later it finally shows the error. Can't really show anything, it's just suddenly as if every change to a file gets recognized minutes later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer.

Somehow *opcache.revalidate_freq* inside the php.ini was set to *200* and *zend_extension=opcache* enabled. I've never changed this manually. Would be interesting to find out what caused the change.